# Getting common value between two different string in Java

Tags: java, string, oop, object, compare

I have two Strings, and I have to get the same value between those strings
here how it is:

```
String tempPath = "TEB-MRI-SUD-KRT-THB-DU-PSG-BOI-RW";
String lewat = "DP-DPB-POC-UI-UP-LNA-TNT-PSM-DRN-CW-TEB-MRI-SUD-KRT-THB-DU-KPB";
```

I want to get the common value between those two strings and make it into another string variable like this

```
String passedPath = "TEB-MRI-SUD-KRT-THB-DU-";
```

variable *passedPath* is the same value of the two string, which later will be used to subtract from the *tempPath* so I can get a new, unvisited path like this

```
tempPath = tempPath.replace(passedPath,"");
// tempPath will then valued as "PSG-BOI-RW"
```

So the question is, how do I get the *passedPath* value from those two strings?
I've tried searching this case in stackoverflow but always directed to another string comparation questions.

Can anybody help me to try achieve this? or direct me to a question with the same case as mine?
thank you :)

*ps: the values in the strings (TEB,MRI,SUD etc) is ordered as it is, so there will be only one occurence if there is any occurence of the same substring in *tempPath* and *lewat*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need to implement an algorithm for solving the
"longest common substring" problem.

See here, there's plenty of good information:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem
Also, Google this *"longest common substring"*.

The simplest solution is probably the dynamic programming approach.

Comment: this is exactly what i needed to fix my problem! i thought there was a function in java to do this, but actually we must use this algorithm.. thank you so much for your help sir! i'll mark this as the answer :)